# HTML/CSS collapsible button for "Read More" not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a "Read More" button so that I could collapse a large piece of text. So far, what I have is the following. However, when I click the "read more" button, it doesn't reveal the rest of the text.

**html**:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <br>
            <center><h1>About Us</h1></center>
            <section class="main items">
            <article class="item">
                <header>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    <h3>John Doe</h3>
                </header>
                <center><img src="static/pic.jpg" style="width:400px;"></img></center>
                <br><br><p>This is where the text I want to show goes.</p>                          
                <button class="collapsible">Read More</button>
                <div class="more_content">
                    <p>This is the text I want to appear after clicking the read more button.</p>
                </div>  
            </article>
        </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->

    <script src="js/collapsible.js"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

**CSS**:

```
/* Style the button that is used to open and close the collapsible content */
.collapsible {
  background-color: #ffbf00;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}


/* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
.more_content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffbf00;
}
```

Here is the added JS as per the suggestions in the comments. However, it still doesn't work when I click the "read me" button.

**JS (collapsible.js)**:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var more_content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (more_content.style.display === "block") {
      more_content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      more_content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: How about that w3 solution? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp

Comment: You're going to need JS to do this, there's no way without it.

Comment: @JBDouble05 I've added the JS script from here (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp) to my js file , however, I'm a bit confused as to where in the above html script I should reference that JS file.

Comment: Probably in `layout.html`?

Comment: Just add this `<script src="filename.js"></script>`

Comment: Okay, I did that and it still doesn't work when I click "read more". See added scripts above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just HTML, and CSS to make it *look* like a button. This would use the  and  tags - though. I'm unsure of your audience so I don't know if that matters to you - but it's an alternative solution.

```
<section>
    <article>
        Text/content you'd like to lead with
    </article>
    <details>
        <summary>Your 'Read More' button</summary>
        Content you'd like to appear after clicking
    </details>
</section>
```

You could use CSS to style the *summary* tag to look like a button.

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhonf5xg/15/

Answer (score 1):

I cannot recommend jQuery enough. For years I didn't want to use it but it is honestly the best/easiest solution. If you want to expand/contract or just show/hide it is perfect.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/